# Let child-div overflow parent

Tags: css, html

I have a div hierarchy like this (with the funktion as name)

```
<Overflow Auto>
   <Background-image>
   <(multiple)bordered divs>
      <PopUpImageDiv/>
   </(multiple)bordered divs>
   </Background-image>
</Overflow Auto>
```

The thing is, I want the Background-Image and the bordered divs overflow auto but the popupImage which needs to be inside the bordered div needs to be overflow:initial so it can expand over the whole screen.

I hope that explanation is clear if it isn't, in a single sentence: 
I want that a child div can flow out of a parent div that has overflow:auto

Comment: *I hope that explanation is clear* - **NO**

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean, what do I take?

Comment: explain more clearly what is that you want ? maybe explation by html code would be simpler to explain and understand.

Comment: The explanation is not clear. Maybe you should post an image in order to ilustrate the issue? Hint: In order to break out of the parents bounds you could work with position:[fixed,relative,absolute] and/or the z-index.

Comment: The problem is, I'm working with someone elses javascript and jquery code, and I'm only making an hotfix for the given stuff so I'm not really into it myself

Comment: @Fanvaron, sure, but it's still possible to override existing CSS with own code (at least with the keyword `!important`) or with own JavaScript/jQuery code. As allready mentioned: use `position:[absoulte, relative or fixed]` and/or the z-index (both in CSS). The CSS `overflow` **is not** what you're looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You're saying a child div can flow out of a parent div that has overflow:auto you can only do this making position of child div absolute.

```
.child-div {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

> position:absolute; z-index: 5;

Your looking for something like this ?